# Object is of type unknown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I was implementing jwt authentication in ionic react with typescript so after implementing it successfully, at the en when i want to add a check in my App.tsx i am getting a typescript error

> Object is of type 'unknown'

Here is my code

```
const App: React.FC<Idecode> = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
    // Set auth token header auth
    const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
    setAuthToken(token);
    // Decode token and get user info and exp
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    console.log(decoded);
    // Set user and isAuthenticated
    dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    // Check for expired token
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // to get in milliseconds

    console.log(decoded.exp, currentTime); //Here when i access exp i get an error

    if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
      // Logout user
      dispatch(logoutUser());

      // Redirect to login
      window.location.href = "./login";
    }
  }

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonRouterOutlet id="menu">
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/verify" component={Verify} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact={true} />
          <Route
            path="/forgot-password"
            component={forgotPassword}
            exact={true}
          />
          <Route path="/set-password" component={setPassword} exact={true} />
        </IonRouterOutlet>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  );
};

export default App;
```

so when i try to get "decoded.exp" ( which i get via my backend after implementing jwt ) contains data like

```
{id: "5f5f30cdbfd0c11d426245e5", email: "ratnabh2615@gmail.com", iat: 1600085677, exp: 1600172077}
```

which is stored in my localstoage in encrypted form and then i decode here

i get error of "Object is of type 'unknown'"

Comment: What line is giving you the error? I'm guessing `const decoded = jwt_decode(token);` Try casting the result of `jwt_decode`

Comment: console.log(decoded.exp, currentTime);  i have also added a comment after it

Comment: Your comment after that line doesn't help us figure out what the problem is. Fix your question to include the error message instead of hidden in a comment. Where does `jwt_decode` come from? Please read up on  how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: updated maybe not its clear ?

Comment: You didn't try to do what I suggested in my first comment and you didn't explain where `jwt_decode` was defined and what it returned. Sorry, but that was as much time as I could give to help

Comment: cool np @JuanMendes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must explicit generic type set for  `const decoded = jwt_decode(token);` to know type of object before it's accessed.

There are many ways. If

- Your function `jwt_decode` is generic function. const decoded = jwt_decode<any| YourDefinedType>(token);
- Or just try: `const decoded : any = jwt_decode(token);`

Updated following your imformation:

```
type JWTDeCode  = {
    id: string,
    email: string,
    iat: number,
    exp: number
}

const decoded : JWTDeCode = jwt_decode(token);
```

Comment: thanks man, gotcha !